# How to jailbreak an Apple Time Capsule?

Tags: router, time-machine, jailbreak, time-capsule

Anyone know of any tools to jailbreak an Apple Time capsule? I'm interested in installing sshd for sshfs access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no longer relevant.

Comment: Sal, is it no longer relevant to you, personally, or because the product is obsolete, or some other reason?  This question is/was obviously of interest to others.  Many questions involve obsolete products (one the other day involved installing something on Win 98).  Can you clarify?  I don't want to vote to close a question that may still be useful to somebody else.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it stands there is no way to jailbreak Apple's Time Capsule or the Airport Extreme. They are running NetBSD but the firmware images are encrypted and no one has broken it thus far.

You can view a couple related questions on ServerFault that have to do with this as well:

- [How to hack Airport Extreme to Support USB 3G Modem](https://serverfault.com/questions/7098/how-to-hack-airport-extreme-to-support-usb-3g-modem)
- Or your original question on ServerFault: [SSH access to Apple Time Capsule](https://serverfault.com/questions/7452/ssh-access-to-apple-time-capsule)

Comment: How do you know these devices are running NetBSD?

Comment: @Chris: There are a couple spots (that I've sadly long forgotten). There are some who decompiled firmware images: http://www.scherello.de/?id=181 while there are also some PDFs that were on the CDs that acknowledged NetBSD.

Comment: hmmm, that blog post you state never explains how he came up with the idea that the TC is running NetBSD.

Comment: well i just stumbled upon this, http://goo.gl/RZIN5P

Answer (score 1):

If you avoid the latest firmware update (7.6) and try to exploit ([like this guy](https://www.dc414.org/2011/04/fun-with-cve-2011-0997/)) the [ISC DHCP bug](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/106987/APPLE-SA-2011-11-10-2.txt) then you might be able to jailbreak the TC....

Comment: thanks! I was going to give up on my time capsule and use a pogo plug for disk sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I would ([and](https://superuser.com/questions/6768/for-os-x-backup-solutions-that-perform-just-like-time-machine/6785#6785) [did](https://superuser.com/questions/7996/os-x-keeps-losing-my-linux-samba-shares/8015#8015)) look at setting up a Linux server running Netatalk to provide Time Machine functionality.

Comment: I like that idea, but I already have a time capsule. I can't justify buying another box right now. At some point I will look for a small form factor linux box with wifi, four eth ports and a pair of hard drive bays.