# Applications with Time Machine integration

Tags: macos, time-machine, text-editors, version-control, integration

Is there a list of Mac applications that integrate with Time Machine?

I think iPhoto has a somewhat hidden feature that allows you to browse previous versions of its library. What else is out there?

What I am specifically looking for is a text editor that uses Time Machine to implement undo across the whole history, and "compare with previous versions". I totally rely on these features in Eclipse, but not all files I need to edit are managed by Eclipse.

Comment: You've meanwhile found [my other post](http://superuser.com/questions/6768/for-os-x-backup-solutions-that-perform-just-like-time-machine/6887#6887), but just for the archives: Wikipedia has [a tiny overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%5FMachine%5F%28Apple%5Fsoftware%29#Time-Machine-aware_applications)

Comment: @Arjan: tiny, indeed :-(

Comment: To clarify, you mean you want something like [E](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) (with "personal revision control") for Mac OS X? And Time Machine support is just one of the ways that could be realized for you? In that case I suggest you edit your question.

Comment: @Daniel: No, Time Machine support is essential (for the purpose of this question).

Comment: @Thilo OK thanks. I'm pretty sure however that no such software exists: It would be too unreliable (no backups for FileVault home directories while logged in, easily disconnected backup drive and users are only warned after 10 days, etc.).

Comment: Agree that it cannot replace something like git, but still, the Time Machine data is there anyway, so some apps might want to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, [time machine backups can be searched with spotlight](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/15136.html).

What it sounds like you're really looking for, is some sort of version control system. [BBEdit integrates nicely with CVS](http://www.macworld.com/article/26375/2003/09/bbeditversioncontrol.html), for example. You can find differences between older versions of a document and the current version.