# Best Back Up Program for Mac

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, backup, nas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup software for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/375/backup-software-for-mac-os-x)

What is the best back up program for a Mac running Snow Leopard? I just need to back up working directories, so I don't need Time Machine or a package that creates a boot image.

I am using a Synology NAS, so [SmartBackup](http://freeridecoding.com/smartbackup/) will not work due to file system incompatibility and [Synk Standard](http://www.decimus.net/synk_standard.php) by Decimus refuses to mount the drive at the right IP. Isn't there a simple, reliable package that will allow me to connect to a real server, rather than the USB drive that I am backing up to now?

Comment: Please see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/375/backup-software-for-mac-os-x) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/6768/for-os-x-backup-solutions-that-perform-just-like-time-machine), among many other duplicates.

Comment: Umm, not sure that answers the question well.

Comment: Your question title is basically a paraphrase of the first link I posted. However, since your specific issue is for a Synology NAS, you may do better by using that in your question title, and giving more details about the problems you have faced with SmartBackup and Synk Standard. It's just that there have been so many "best backup" questions here that if you don't want to be overlooked, you'll need to provide many more details about exactly what you're looking for. Otherwise you'll get a generic answer like *Carbon Copy Cloner* as below. Best of luck!

Comment: Considering that the duplicate question lists all possible options and is meant to stay up to date, there is nothing in your question that makes it anything but a duplicate.